# Is it possible to change EOL setting in .gitattributes without need to normalize all files?

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have a repository, there's a mixture of CRLF and LF. With new pull requests, new EOL changes are produced, which is annoying. Is there a way to setup the .gitattributes in a way that:

1. When you check in something (writing into the object database), it will get normalized (to LF).
2. You do not have to change all EOLs in the whole repository, which produces huge amount of unwanted changes that harden blaming etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, but it's moderately painful: add each file you modify, one at a time, to `.gitattributes` to specify it (by pathname) as text.  That is, you'd start with a `.gitattributes` reading:

```
* binary
```

Then, whenever you (or anyone) works on some file named, say, `dir/sub/phile.ext`, you would also edit `.gitattributes` to read:

```
* binary
dir/sub/file.ext text
```

so that the file with that *one specific name* will have all its line-endings normalized from then on.

When you've edited 1352 out of 3000 files, your `.gitattributes` will have 1353 lines in it: 1352 for the files, plus the `* binary` up front.  At some point (around 1500 out of 3000 files), it will become easier to invert the list: list every file that *is not* to be treated as text, with a `* text` line up front.  From then on, every time you edit a file, *remove* it from `.gitattributes`.  When you've edited 2999 out of the 3000 files, your `.gitattributes` will be down to just two lines:

```
* text
path/to/never-edited.zog binary
```

Note that you can split one large `.gitattributes` file into smaller files, one per sub-directory: if you have edited every file in `dir/sub` at this point, you can take them out of the top level `.gitattributes` and have `dir/sub/.gitattributes` list all its files as `* text`, for instance.

The key to this is that the *last matching line* for some attribute applies to the file, and `.gitattribute` files are read from the top level first, down to the most-specific sub-directory last, so top-level `.gitattributes` lines are overridden by `dir/.gitattributes` lines, which in turn are overridden by `dir/sub/.gitattributes` lines, when working on files within `dir/sub`.